# Add two values ​in mysql

Tags: mysql

I enter in the database the value with this format `1 000.00`.
I want to add two values ​​of this format, for example `1 000.00 + 4 000.00` like this:

```
CAST(SUM(1 000.00 + 4 000.00) AS DECIMAL (15 , 2 )) AS Pago
```

the returned value is `5` and should be `5 000.00`

Comment: do you really have spaces in your numbers?

Comment: it's hard to tell exactly what you are asking; please edit your question to show some sample data (create table and insert statements, as text, not images) and your desired results for that sample data

Comment: @ysth yes I have

Comment: @ysth I think I explained it well, the problem is spaces. I don't ask, I show that it returns 5 and the expected should be 5 000.00

Comment: Hi @Bruno do you wanna add this value as decimal or string in database? space between digit treat as string.

Comment: Rahul Biswas The field where I enter these values ​​is a string, `varchar`

Comment: you may think you explained it well, but I'm telling you you haven't.  it is unclear if you are adding separate columns or the same column in separate rows, for instance.  and your sample expression is not valid syntax, which leaves the type of source data unclear.  showing sample data that answerers can actually try out makes things much more clear

Comment: try it my way next time, and you will not only get fewer negative votes (that wasn't me, I didn't vote) but will also likely get an answer within a very few minutes that works the first time

Comment: I'm not just making this stuff up; I'm trying to give you the essence of https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mysql/info#how-to-ask-a-good-and-answerable-question-b5fm

Answer (score -1):

Sum 2 values and finally add a space

```
-- MySQL
SELECT INSERT((SUM(CAST(REPLACE('1 000.00', ' ', '') AS decimal(15, 2)) + CAST(REPLACE('4 000.00', ' ', '') AS decimal(15, 2)))), 2, 0, ' ') sum_total
```

Please check url https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=b8ab1e7c4c1d2ab596fbc1fe58754cf8

Add these two values in a table

```
SELECT INSERT((SUM(CAST(REPLACE(apago, ' ', '') as decimal(15, 2)))), 2, 0, ' ') pago FROM test;
```

Please check this url https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=65fa6af1bedd4a1acce01dc0ea700dd6

Comment: Hi @Bruno please check this query and let me know if you've any query regard this.

Comment: I'm trying it this way: `SELECT INSERT((SUM(CAST(REPLACE('A.Pago', ' ', '') AS decimal(15, 2)))), 2, 0, ' ') AS Pago`, but it returns 0.00

Comment: Hi @Bruno 'A.pago' is string.. You want to add 2 numbers.

Comment: `A.pago` is a string, with the values ​​1 000.00 and 4 000.00 and I want to add them up

Comment: Hi @Bruno please check new one... this value is inserted in a table as string. If any casting needed in a final result for storing in a DB please do that. If you've different value but add space in a second position as per format please consider the result in a string and add space in second position.

Comment: SUM is for summing across rows; totally unneeded here (unless that is what they are really wanting to do)

Comment: Hi @ysth it's his requirement. I try to answer the question and pick the desired result.

Answer (score -1):

I resolved it this way. First I removed the space in the string like this:

```
SELECT Id, Total, Metodo, REPLACE(Pago, ' ', '') AS Pago

FROM dados.Orcamento
```

Then I added the string:

```
SELECT B.Id, B.Total, B.Metodo, CAST(SUM(B.Pago) AS DECIMAL (15 , 2 )) AS Pago

FROM 
(SELECT Id, Total, Metodo, REPLACE('Pago', ' ', '') AS Pago
    
FROM dados.Orcamento) AS B GROUP BY B.Id, B.Metodo, B.Total ORDER BY B.Id ASC LIMIT 1
```

So the 5000.00 returned

Comment: so you wanted 5000.00 returned, not "5 000.00"?

Comment: @ysth yes, I intended to add 1 000.00 + 4 000.00, the result was intended to be correct, which was 5000.00 or 5 000.00, but returning 5000.00 then I use maskMoney to put the value back like this: 5 000.00

Comment: But @Bruno you wanted 5 000.00 in your question.